# Reselect the chosen option with 'chosen' plugin. JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the Harvest chosen plugin with Jquery. Everything works fine and when I select one of the options it becomes selected, with some styles applied to it: I'am using (Allow Deselect on Single Select): [link](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen).

The problem is when I refresh the page I want that selected value to be re rendered.

I tried to understand Chosen properties an methods, such as: Chosen.result_activate() or
Chosen.result_select(), but I'am not sure how to use them.

here is my html:

```
        <div id="container">
    <div class="side-by-side clearfix">
           <div class="side-by-side clearfix">
        <select id ="combooptions" data-placeholder="Search drafts" style="width:200px" class="chzn-select-deselect" tabindex="7">
          <option value=""></option>
 </select><span style="margin-left:5px;cursor:pointer;color:blue;text-decoration:underline;" id="draftInsert"> Insert</span>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

> **EDIT:**
>
> actually my sample  is not in jQuery(document).ready() but in separate function, which is reloaded all the time.And is actually
>   not refresh page but a updatepanel refresh.  sorry for
>   misunderstanding. My page is not reloading the document.ready I guess.

and here is my js:

```
    var saveseleted='';
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    for (var i in combonews) {
            jQuery("#combooptions").append("<option value='" + combonews[i][0] + "'>" + combonews[i][1] + "</option>");
               }

        jQuery(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true });

jQuery('#combooptions').change(function () {
        saveseleted= jQuery("#combooptions :selected").val();
    });
    });
```

and then I after page refresh I need the 'saveselected' option value to be re-chosen automatically.

Please help me,

**UPDATE:**

```
jQuery("#combooptions option").eq(saveseleted).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Doesn't work

Comment: Is there any way you could provide a demo page that illustrates the problem? Seeing the entire thing might help. A [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be fantastic.

Comment: OK just give me some time. thanks

Comment: Sorry,if it sounds dumb, but I had to ask it.. have you tried jQuery("#combooptions").val(saveseleted)?

Comment: @user2008945 I deleted my answer (because it ended up not being useful), but that's one of the suggestions I made, and it apparently didn't work.

Comment: I knew it was a dumb question.

Comment: Anthony Grist: I don't know the reason But it's not fully functioning on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AuY75/  css is not aplied. .it's working locally on my computer. If it possible to make it work, and then I can show my scenario.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing this could be the answer:

```
 jQuery("#combooptions").val(saveseleted);  //update the value first

 jQuery("#combooptions").trigger("liszt:updated");   //trigger this event
```

This trigger event will force the plugin to get updated.

Comment: WOW, first I didn't pay attention, but I tried, and then ....I can't believe it's working. I just put this two lines of code:)  Thank you user2008945 and Anthony Grist as well you made my day. by the way I don't quite understand what 'liszt' is. is it refers to any plugin methods, or...?thank you any way

Comment: Neither do I.. I guess its just a name of the event that was selected to avoid any conflict with other plugins (coz its odd enough name) and is tracked by the 'chosen' plugin to get the signal when to update itself.

Comment: Remember in version 1.0.0, you'll need to change liszt to chosen:
https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/releases/tag/1.0.0